# Reparametrization trick in Flux.jl

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, julia, flux.jl

Does `Flux.jl` have an equivalent to `rsample` in `PyTorch` that automatically implements these stochastic/policy gradients. That way the reparameterized sample becomes differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching and asking about it on Julia discourse, it seems that there is no such thing as `rsample` in Julia to simplify the reparametrization trick. However, there seem to be certain works that have not been shared yet, but they might be soon.

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/reparametrization-trick-in-flux-jl/100489